# How to pass django model field value as an argument to callable which is default of field in the same model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is what I want to do:

```
def createNewsletterHash():
    hash = hashlib.sha256()
    hash.update(str(time.time()))
    hash.update(emailValueOfThisModel) # HOW TO DO THIS?
    return hash.hexdigest()

class NewsletterSubscriber(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, unique=True)
    hash = models.CharField(default=createNewsletterHash, unique=True)
```

I am assuming that it is impossible to get the values of other fields at time of creation of object. But is there a cleaner way of doing this then setting the hash value after object creation or setting it explicitly at the time of creation like:

```
NewsletterSubscriber.objects.create(email='email@email.com', hash=createNewsletterHash('email@email.com'))
```

and not using the default parameter for hash field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get values of other fields at creation time in the `save` method of your model.

```
class NewsletterSubscriber(...):
    ...
    hash = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk: # this will ensure that the object is new
            self.hash = createNewsLetterHash(self.email)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Why did you set blank parameter to `True`? I do not want to allow the `hash` field ever to be blank, and if I always fill it at creation time it makes no sense to allow it to be blank, right?

Comment: @dsalaj I added `blank=True` so that when a user submits the form, no error is raised because user is not responsible for the hash. It will be filled automatically in background, therefore will never actually be blank. I think you are confusing `blank=True` with `null=True`.

Comment: I defined my from in `forms.py` with `fields = ['email']`. No field in the model has `blank=True` and there is no error produced when a user submits the form. I tried setting the `blank=False` explicitly, still no error. The same with `null=False`. I also tried removing the `save` method override, still the same behavior. Now I'm really confused with why the django doesn't report any errors (i.e. the has is stored as empty string `u''` in the model).

Comment: @dsalaj Django only reports errors for fields which are present in your form.   Don't worry, there's no need to set `blank=True` if everything is working fine for you otherwise (*Don't fix it if it ain't broke*). I think I got you confused about all this. :P Ignore my previous comments.